queryClient.refetchQueries does not work but works why?
trying to refetch data but kinda work but not really.
queryClient.refetchQueries("getOrders");
works but ts error
[{
    "resource": "/home/tf/github/zerodha-copy-next/src/app/zerodha/_components/Rightside/Order.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2769",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 2, '(filters?: RefetchQueryFilters<unknown> | undefined, options?: RefetchOptions | undefined): Promise<void>', gave the following error.\n    Type '\"getOrders\"' has no properties in common with type 'RefetchQueryFilters<unknown>'.\n  Overload 2 of 2, '(queryKey?: QueryKey | undefined, filters?: RefetchQueryFilters<unknown> | undefined, options?: RefetchOptions | undefined): Promise<...>', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'readonly unknown[]'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 46,
    "startColumn": 34,
    "endLineNumber": 46,
    "endColumn": 45
}]

queryClient.refetchQueries(["getOrders"]);
does't work but no ts error
why? and how to fix ts error

Please provide more code snippets and explain how and where you use them with code examples. This will help us understand the issue better.
